# What is the use of @ symbol in the C language?

Tags: symbols

The symbol @ was seen in one of my programs. But I could not find out why it is used .

The syntax is

```
 const unsigned char Array_name[] @(INFO_Array+1) = {................};
```

Comment: Are you sure that the program is written in plain C (and not with parts in Objective-C)?

Comment: It's probably indeed Objective-C. [Boxed expressions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions) I think.

Comment: I think that was an embedded C @user3652454

Comment: Maybe a plain C macro that is named `@` ? Eg `#define @(_)` or for some attribute.

Comment: #define INFO_Array      0x1900
const unsigned char Array_name[] @(INFO_Array+1) = {................};

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `@` operator can be different for the particular compiler in which the code is compiled.

For example, in IAR Embedded Workbench's C/C++ compiler the `@` operator can be used for [placing global and static variables at absolute addresses.](http://www.iarsys.co.jp/download/LMS2/arm/7502/ewarm7502doc/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf)

If you are using IAR C/C++ compiler, the compiler will place `Array_name` in the address `(INFO_Array+1)`.

`@` operator can also be used to place a variable or object in a particular section of the object file:

```
uint32_t CTRL_OFFSET_x86 @ "MY_RAM_SECTION";
```

The above line will place `CTRL_OFFSET_x86` in the object file section `MY_RAM_SECTION`.

`#pragma location` can also be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a compiler flag to disable interpreting the string "INFO_Array+1" as an expression. In [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), for example, you can use the @ operator to tell the compiler to use the following expression as String without trying to evaluate it.

A quick googling showed:

For example, this line will fail to compile:

```
int new = 1776;   // 'new' is a keyword
```

However, this line compiles without error:

```
int @new = 1776;
```

Comment: No, this does not transfer from C# to C.